# If $f(x) \leq 0$ $\forall x$, prove that $\forall r$, if the limit as $x$ goes to $r$ exists, then the limit is $\leq 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Assume f is a function defined on all of R and that f(x) $\leq$ 0 for all x. Prove that for any r if $lim_{x->r}$ f(x) exists, then the limit is $\leq$ 0.

I will let $lim_{x->r}$ f(x) = $l$. Now I know that for every $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists $\delta$ > 0 s.t. for all real numbers x, if 0 < |x - r| < $\delta$, then |f(x) - l| < $\epsilon$. Now I have that l - $\epsilon$ < f(x) < l + $\epsilon$, and since f(x) $\leq$ 0, I have l - $\epsilon$ $\leq$ 0.

Logically, it makes sense that l is less than or equal to zero because we can have epsilon be arbitrarily close to zero. However, I don't know how to make this a more rigorous proof.

Comment: Here's an angle of attack: what happens if $l>0$?  Specifically, what are the function values 'near' $r$?  Can they stay less than or equal to 0 for values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $r$?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot figure out what you have written but the gist of the proof is this. Suppose the function $f$ attains a positive limit $l \gt 0$ at some point $ r \in \Bbb R $. Then there must be a neighbourhood around $ r  $ such that the function $f$ is positive for every element in that neigbourhood which should not happen if $f(x) \le 0$ for each $x \in \Bbb R$. The rigorous proof is thus.

Make the aforementioned assumption. Then pick $\epsilon =  l \gt 0$. Then there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that $$ |x - r| \lt \delta \implies |f(x) - l| \lt \epsilon  \implies   l - \epsilon \lt f(x) \lt l + \epsilon $$

But $l - \epsilon  = 0$ and hence $ x \in (r - \delta, r + \delta) \implies f(x) \gt 0 $ leading to a big fat contradiction.